# Unique scheduled jobs in ActiveMQ

Tags: ruby, scheduled-tasks, activemq-classic, stomp

I've multiple nodes (let's say instances of an application in a cluster) able to publish scheduled messages to ActiveMQ (cron-like). What I want to achieve is to have only unique jobs scheduled (to avoid duplicated tasks).

Is there any way to publish message only if it isn't set to be scheduled?
Is there any way to list messages in scheduled queue before pushing to it?

Maybe the correct solution would be to "clean the queue and then publish" approach?

I'm using "stomp" gem on Ruby.

I was googling a lot. I know I could write plugin (interceptor) to handle unique messages but maybe there is another way to do it.

Comment: Do you use quartz as scheduler ?

Comment: No, I have custom producer which publishes messages and custom consumers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but just in case this helps someone down the road: ActiveMQ supports message deduplication. You can set a special property on your message to some custom ID. If message deduplication is enabled, the next message with the same ID will be dropped.

More info here: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/duplicate-detection.html